# Копирование файла без расширения

Tags: php

Имеется файл `$a = '/disk/6e8/6e80c754cb74eb00fa5999ce8a000348'`  (без расширения)

как его скопировать чтобы получилось

`$b = '/disk/old/6e80c754cb74eb00fa5999ce8a000348.docx'`
(не переименовать, а скопировать)

`copy($a, $b)` не срабатывает...

Подскажите как по другому скопировать файл?

Answer (score 1):

Каталог `/disk/old/` существует? Функция `copy` не умеет создавать каталоги, только копирует файлы в уже существующие. Если существует - проверьте доступ к ней.

Comment: нет всё существует и права верные прописаны.. вопрос в том что файл который я пытаюсь скопировать без расширения *.docx

Comment: Только что проверил:

`$a = './6e80c754cb74eb00fa5999ce8a000348';
$b = './old/6e80c754cb74eb00fa5999ce8a000348.docx';

copy($a, $b);`

Всё скопировалось, у каталога `old` права 0777.

Comment: странно у меня не копирует. права стоят 775.  сделал через  exec("cp ".$strFilename." ".$this->_tempFileName); всё заработало